# Trying to create multiple markers on Google Map from database lat longs

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, google-maps, loops

I have a database that gets latitude and longitude values inserted into it.  I have created a PHP loop to pull these values out in an array and my hope is to create a marker for each point on a Google map.  Here is the code that I need to adjust to do so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mylat,mylong,request;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   zoom:7,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 });


mylat= <?php echo $postalLat; ?>;
mylong = <?php echo $postalLong; ?>;
request = {
origin: mylat+','+mylong,
destination: '<?php echo $latRefDef; ?><?php echo $this->item->gpslat; ?>,<?php echo     $longRefDef; ?><?php echo $this->item->gpslong; ?>',
travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
 };


 directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
 directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));
 directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
 directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
 document.getElementById('loader').innerHTML = "";

   }
 });


//omitted database connection here to get array of values

$totalMarkers = count($results);

foreach($results as $result){
$gpsLats[] = $result->gpslat; 
$gpsLongs[] = $result->gpslong; 
}


$i = 0;
while ($i < $totalMarkers) {
$inc = $i++;

?>

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $gpsLats[$inc]; ?>,<?php echo $gpsLongs[$inc]; ?>);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Hello World!'
  });

<?php

}

?>

</script>
```

My thought was that since the javascript which creates each marker is within the while loop then I would get one marker per entry.  Unfortunately this is not functioning as I would like it to, any ideas on how to adjust it?

Comment: How do you create the map?  Do you get any map or markers? Can you provide the code the browser sees? Maybe some sample latitudes and longitudes?  What do you mean by  "is not functioning as I would like it"?  How about a fiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: @geocodezip I have added more code context to the question.  This should help you see how I am building out the map.  There is a map which provides driving directions between two points and I would like to place the markers throughout this map.  Thanks

Comment: In general, [your code works](http://jsfiddle.net/a9Rc7/) if I wrap it in an initialize function and wait for the DOM to finish loading, but as you haven't provided any sample data, that could be the problem.

Comment: @geocodezip thanks, that fiddle really helped me solve it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure why it wasn't working out with all that php code, but I whittled it down to this and it works now:

```
<?php
while ($i < $totalMarkers) {
$inc = $i++; 
$myLats = $gpsLats[$inc];
$myLogns = $gpsLongs[$inc];
?>
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $myLats; ?>,<?php echo $myLogns; ?>);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Hello World!'
  });
<?php

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not attaching the map marker to the map itself, just creating the marker object.  I usually use something like this:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker',{'position':new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(<?php  echo $gpsLats[$inc]; ?>),parseFloat(<?php echo $gpsLongs[$inc]; ?>)});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I define the marker.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                title: "Test Marker",
                visible: true,
                map:myMap
            });
```

And attach it to map

```
marker.setMap(myMap);
```

Just try if this helps. Just a thought, are the correct coordinates being output?

Comment: I tried, but still no markers.  I have tested the coordinates and they look good in the php values.

Comment: Any Javascript errors in firebug or any other tool you may be using?

Comment: ultimately I had to move all the php above the while loop out of the javascript and it now works.  Thanks for the input.